# Java Median Error

Tags: java

I need help with a piece of code I'm writing. I want to compute the median of an array. Initially the types were all ints and it compouted the median with integer division which gave me a wrong answer. I changed everything to doubles but I'm getting a type mismatch error saying I can't convert doubles to ints which doesn't really make sense. Can someone help. This is my code:

```
public class MedianTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      double median = 0;
      double myValues[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

      double arrayHalfOdd = ((myValues.length - 1) / 2) + 1;
      double arrayHalfEven = ((myValues.length - 1) / 2);

      if ((myValues.length - 1) % 2 == 0) {
         median = (myValues[arrayHalfEven] + myValues[arrayHalfEven + 1]) / 2;
      } else {
         median = myValues[arrayHalfOdd];
      }
      System.out.print(median);
   }

}
```

the errors are in the myValues[arrayHalfEven] and myValues[arrayHalfOdd]

By the way this IS NOT homework

Comment: Don't forget to make your code safe against lists of only 1 element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

final answer:

```
    if (myValues.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    else if (myValues.length == 1) {
        return myValues[0];
    }
    else {
        int halfRoundedUp = myValues.length / 2;
        if (myValues.length % 2 == 0) { // even count, average the middle values
            return (myValues[halfRoundedUp - 1] + myValues[halfRoundedUp]) / 2;
        }
        else { // odd, take the middle value
            return myValues[halfRoundedUp];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a double as array index: arrayHalfOdd and arrayHalfEven

Make those guys ints.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, you can use Math.round(double d) or Math.trunc(double d);

```
int arrayHalfOdd = Math.round(((myValues.length - 1 ) / 2)) + 1;
int arrayHalfEven = Math.round(((myValues.length - 1 ) / 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

you are indexing into an array using double values `arrayHalfEven` and `arrayHalfOdd`.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
median = (myValues[arrayHalfEven] + myValues[arrayHalfEven + 1]) / 2;
```

and this line

```
median = myValues[arrayHalfOdd];
```

are using your double variables arrayHalfEven and arrayHalfOdd as array indices. If the compiler allowed double array indices, you could try and access a position at a non-integer array index (e.g. array[1.5]) which would cause crazy memory access complications. So, instead it throws an error.

Luckily, the type of arrayHalfEven and arrayHalfOdd doesn't affect whether the compiler uses integer division.

Integer division will only happen when *both* the numerator and denominator of an equation are integers. The array indices aren't part of the numerator or the denominator; they're *selecting* the numerator from your array.

So if the elements of the array (the numerators) are doubles you won't get integer division. If you want them to be integers, you can still prevent integer division by making your literal denominator a double, like this:

```
median = (myValues[arrayHalfEven] + myValues[arrayHalfEven + 1]) / 2.0;
```

Then you won't get integer division even if the array items are integers.